# ExecuteNonQuery() returns value > 0 but inserted row does not appear in table

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, insert

```
ADD BUTTON ACTIONS
  Private Sub cmdAddProduct_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdAddProduct.Click
    'DATABASE CONNECITON
    Dim connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Deeposdb.accdb")
    connection.Open()
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Stock,CostPrice, UnitPrice) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", connection)
    Dim validField As Boolean = ValidateFields(txtProductName.Text, numProductStock.Value, txtCostPrice.Text, txtSellingPrice.Text)

    If validField = True Then
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtProductName.Text
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stock", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(numProductStock.Value)
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", OleDbType.Double).Value = Convert.ToDouble(txtSellingPrice.Text)
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@CostPrice", OleDbType.Double).Value = Convert.ToDouble(txtCostPrice.Text)


      Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

      If rowsAffected > 0 Then
        MsgBox("SAVED PRODUCTS SUCCESSFULLY")
        dtvInventory.Update()
      Else
        MsgBox("SAVING PRODUCTS FAILED")
      End If

    Else
      MsgBox("COMPLETE ALL FIELDS TO PROCEED")
    End If
    connection.Close()


  End Sub
```

The problem is it returns saved successfully, yet no data appears on the datatable.
my table name is "Products", table Fields are:
are ProductID (Primary Key autogenerated), ProductName, Stock, UnitPrice, SellingPrice

The control fields are
txtProductName (textbox)
numProductStock (numericupdown)
txtCostPrice (textbox)
txtSellingPrice (textbox)

Comment: While some languages commonly use upper-case letters, please don't write normal sentences (not even titles) in all upper case. Writing in all upper-case is considered shouting, and it's very rude to shout at the people you want to help you.

Comment: MsgBox isn't really VB.NET, however, [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.messagebox?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) is. You may consider separating your UI code from your database code (ie: create a function for the database code and return the number of rows affected). MessageBox is blocking, so any code after it, won't execute until the "OK" button is pressed. In OLEDB, order of parameters matters, which it looks like you're aware of, however, you've switched the order of the last two parameters. It's unclear where you're storing your database.

Comment: What do you mean by "the datatable"? Do you mean the database table, or do you mean a DataTable object in your app?

Comment: If `ExecuteNonQuery` is returning a value greater than zero then the data was inserted successfully. If you're not seeing it in the database then you're either looking in the wrong place or the right place at the wrong time. That's not as crazy as it sounds and is very common with database files. In that case, you should read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/archive/blogs/vsdata/debugging-with-local-database-file) to learn how local data files are handled.

Comment: If you mean a `DataTable` object in your app then why are you calling `ExecuteNonQuery` in the first place? You should be adding the data to the `DataTable` first, then calling `Update` on a data adapter to save the changes to the database.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, sorry about the shouting. Not deliberate..

Comment: You can always **[edit]** your questions to improve them. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: What is dtvInventory in this context?  See you're calling it's Update() method.  Could that be a data adapter overwriting the changes you've just made?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few things.

first up, we should use STRONG typed parameter's. This not only ensures we have the correct data types, but also tends to be "less" messy code.

And of course I assume that your including the connection string code in this example is just that - an example, since we don't want to write/have that connection string in code over and over.

And as a general rule, you ALSO want to ensure that you close the connection after you are done.

Also, even access (since 2000 - a long time ago) now uses uni-code characters, so in place of varchar, you should be using nvarchar.

Also, you don't provide enough information as to what numproduct.value is? Is that a type-o on your part, or in fact does that use .value in place of .text?

So, lets put together all of the above.

First up, the connection:

file->Project-> project properties.

Then settings:

And thus this:

[image]

So, we can now use the connecting builder (nice), but MORE important is we now have ONE connection string that we can/will use everything in the applicaton. (and thus can change the database used with ease).

So,

select change (defualt is sql server), and then browse to your access db file.

You should see/have this:

[image]

Don't forget to click on advanced, we need to check/see/ensure that we are going to use ACE in place of JET. If you are using a mdb file, then you can use JET, but for newer accDB, then you need to select ACE.

And trying to keep this post realative short, ACE also has a x64 bit option, one that we may well want to choose in the future.

More FYI:
If you are using vs2022, then this is the FIRST version of VS that is x64 bits. IN the past, you could always click on "test connection" in above, but now for vs2022, you find that "test connection" button will not work (unless you installed and are using access (or ACE) x64 bits. So, while the connection builder as per above can be used, the test connection button does not (in general) work due to x64 bits.

Also, you MUST force your project to run as x32 bits now. That is this option:

[image]

If you don't have the x86 option, then choose configuration manager, and create a x86 choice - you MUST now do this for vs2022, as once again, even hitting f5 to run results in a x64 bit run of your code, and you need/want to run as x32 bits.

Ok, so now we have the connection issue dealt with, and also dealt with the x32 vs x64 bit issue.

Now, for your code, I suggest this:

```
ValidateFields(txtProductName.Text,
                numProductStock.Value,
                txtCostPrice.Text,
                txtSellingPrice.Text)

    If validField Then

        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.AccessDB)

            Dim strSQL As String =
                "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Stock, CostPrice, UnitPrice) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtProductName.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stock", OleDbType.Integer).Value = numProductStock.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CostPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = txtCostPrice.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = txtSellingPrice.Text
                Dim rowsAffected As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                If rowsAffected > 0 Then
                    MsgBox("SAVED PRODUCTS SUCCESSFULLY")
                    dtvInventory.Update()
                Else
                    MsgBox("SAVING PRODUCTS FAILED")
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    Else
        MsgBox("COMPLETE ALL FIELDS TO PROCEED")
    End If
```

NOW WHY did I break out the code, remove as MUCH wrapping as possbile?

Well, we found a bug. Note how the order of your update does NOT match the order of the parameter's. Unfortunately, when using Access, the order of the parameter's MUST match the update.

So, you have to flip/move/change the cost, and unit parameter's in your command object.

we see/had this:

```
            Dim strSQL As String =
              "INSERT INTO Products (ProductName, Stock, CostPrice, UnitPrice) 
                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProductName", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = txtProductName.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Stock", OleDbType.Integer).Value = numProductStock.Value
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = txtSellingPrice.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@CostPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = txtCostPrice.Text
```

note how unitprice and cost price are NOT in the correct order.

So, with code "easy" to read, then finding issues ALSO becomes easy to read.

We need this:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@CostPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = txtCostPrice.Text
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = txtSellingPrice.Text
```

I also took a wild guess, and you have to check the Access database, since if you using "currency" data type in Access, then you best do the same in the above OleDbType settings.

So, the REAL moral of the story here? Try to reduce all that "wrapping" of code. The instanat I copy + pasted your code, we could see this:

However, we don't see/know what dtInventory supposed to do (should not effect our insert).

However, so far, your posted code did/does look ok, and should work.

I would double check you are updating the correct database.

Comment: Thank you guys, it worked out for me. i appreciated every suggestion.